# В Хроме не открываются другие страницы домена, когда скрипт PHP выполняется

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. 
Например, запускаю скрипт с CURL-запросом. Перехожу на вторую вкладку моего же сайта, чтобы не смотреть на страницу загрузки, а сайт-то все ровно не загружается, пока работа скрипта не закончится в первой вкладке . 
Такое почему-то вижу в хроме . 
Объясните почему так происходит и можно ли исправить ? 
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в сессиях может быть дело

попробуйте в файл с `curl` запросом добавить:

```
session_destroy();
```

Answer (score 1):

Дело не в PHP, не совсем в браузере, а в настройках сервера.

Это ограничение **на сервере** для одной сессии браузера.

Открывайте вторую копию сайта в режиме инкогнито.